# "rails server" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am using window 7. 
I have upgraded rails 2.0.2 to rails 3.0.9 with ruby as 1.8.7. I have changed in evironment.rb as:

> RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '3.0.9' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

still I am unable to start server.

> RubyGems Environment:
>     - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.7.2
>     - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i386-mingw32]
>     - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
>     - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/bin/ruby.exe
>     - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/bin
>     - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
>       - ruby
>       - x86-mingw32
>     - GEM PATHS:
>        - C:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
>        - C:/Users/SUKETA/.gem/ruby/1.8
>     - GEM CONFIGURATION:
>        - :update_sources => true
>        - :verbose => true
>        - :benchmark => false
>        - :backtrace => false
>        - :bulk_threshold => 1000
>        - :sources => ["http://gems.github.com", "http://rubygems.org/"]
>     - REMOTE SOURCES:
>        - http://gems.github.com
>        - http://rubygems.org/

Any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it can help you:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1

Is part of a complete guide that explain how to do this migration on the right way.

However according to http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/9/4/ruby-on-rails-2-3-9-released (official Rails blog) it is recommended to first migrate to Rails 2.3.9

Answer (score 0):

Migrating from rails 2.0.2 to Rails 3 isn't exactly a simple task. To give you an idea Ryan Bates made 3 screencast about this. You can find out more here; http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1

Comment: The link is very useful but alas, many commands are worthless as I am using windows 7. Is there any information you know which can guide like the same for windows instead of linux.